# Redirect error message to /dev/null in if condition

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, test

I have the following `if` statement:

```
if [ "$sourcelast" = "$maxhostlast" ] || [ "$sourcelast" = "$minhostlast" ] || [ "$sourcelast" < "$maxhostlast" ] || [ "$sourcelast" > "$minhostlast" ] ;then ... fi
```

Now I want that the error message is sent to `/dev/null` every time an error occur.

How can I do this?

Comment: Which error message?
From the code inside the if or does the if condition produce an error?

Comment: if you have an error inside the if's condition then maybe you are doing something wrong! so in my opinion your code is broken from the beginning.

Comment: you can also use `exec 2>/dev/null` to ignore all error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going further, you have to fix your syntax. `>` and `<` are shell redirection operators, not comparison operator inside old test `[...]`. [In some shells, you can escape them `\<` and `\>` to archive string comparison](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222656/38906), or using new test `[[...]]`.

It sounds like you want numeric comparison in this case, so you should stick with standard operator `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, `-ge`:

```
if [ "$sourcelast" = "$maxhostlast" ]   ||
   [ "$sourcelast" = "$minhostlast" ]   ||
   [ "$sourcelast" -lt "$maxhostlast" ] ||
   [ "$sourcelast" -gt "$minhostlast" ]
then
  : "Do something"
fi
```

To redirect all error message from all conditions, you can simply wrap them in a subshell:

```
if (
     [ "$sourcelast" = "$maxhostlast" ]   ||
     [ "$sourcelast" = "$minhostlast" ]   ||
     [ "$sourcelast" -lt "$maxhostlast" ] ||
     [ "$sourcelast" -gt "$minhostlast" ]
   ) 2>/dev/null
then
  : "Do something"
fi
```

Comment: For numeric comparison you can also use `(( sourcelast < maxhostlast ))`.

Comment: Is it really possible for this kinds of conditions to produce messages on stderr?

Comment: @michas `((...))` isn't POSIX, you may want to use `$((...))` instead. Yes, it's possible, try `if [ 1 = = 1 ] || [ 1 = 1 ]; then echo 1; fi`